# Detecting the over current and cutting off the supply

Tags: current

I have a load which draws current from the source that is less than 500mA. If by any chance, the load becomes heavy and starts drawing a current which is more than 500mA, this over-current should be detected and the supply should be cut-off to load.I need a solution using **no** ICs ie. only with discrete components.

I have already tried with transistor and also been able to detect the over current, but i am struggling to cut-off the supply to the load.

Comment: Once the supply is cut-off, what mechanism would you use for restarting the supply? You need to consider that some circuits will always leave a residual current flowing through the load in order to "tell" that the heavy load condition has ended... then the supply can be restored. Some circuits will automatically retry power briefly then fall-back to zero if the current is too high. You need to think about this but maybe someone knows a really clever circuit that works in a different way.

Comment: Why no ICs?  Using ICs would be simpler and probably take less board space.

Comment: Andy: Basically i need to latch the over-current condition using some technique. I have thought of using a hardware reset button connected between a capacitor and a ground. In my circuit i am over current is detected and is shunted to charge the capacitor. So once the capacitor is discharged the   circuit returns to its normal operating condition.

Comment: Olin: Thinking of low-cost solution, hence going for the one with discrete components.

Comment: May I know the reason for down-voting this question from the person who has done it. Please let me know the reason!

Comment: Why would a non-IC solution necessarily be less expensive than an IC-based one?

Comment: Anindo: That is what I thought ! If you have a cheaper IC solution, just let me know. We better don't lose focus on the actual question here.

Comment: Have you looked at current-limiting ICs? What is the voltage?

Comment: Leon: Voltage is 5V

Comment: What about the other question?

Comment: yeah. i went through few ICs from linear technology which i felt little costlier. So thought of going with discrete components.

Comment: Have you looked at [polyfuses](http://www.littelfuse.com/data/en/Product_Brochures/EC327-E_Polyfuse_PTC.pdf)?

Comment: Hi Dave: Yeah. I even looked at Polyfuses such as PTCs. I dont get the higher accuracy with polyfuse. Another problem with fuses is that they are either single use fuses or resettable fuses. Here i dont want the fuse to automatically reset itself instead i need to latch that state.

Comment: A polyfuse doesn't reset until you remove the power. I'm curious though: What is the nature of the load, and why can't you fix the overcurrent problem there?

Comment: I think you want to make short circuit protector for your power supply, it is very easy to make one with simple one relay and shunt resistor only, no transistor or any other component needed, google a bit

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have very strict requirements for how fast the cut-off is or how sharp it needs to be, polyfuses can be a great way to go. I put them on all of my designs.

They start to shut off when the current going through them gets too high. How fast they shut off depends on how much overcurrent they are. Once they're off, they stay shut off until you power-cycle the board. They're not great for enforcing a precise current limit, but they're perfect for preventing catastrophic failures.

Here's a sample:

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/MINISMDC050F-2/MINISMDC050FCT-ND/1045862

In quantity 1, it costs $0.35. In quantity 1,000, it's around $0.17. It'll (barely) pass 500mA through it (250-300mA will get through fine), and will shut off pretty hard at 1A. It's dead-simple to use - just put it in-line with your source and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a [PIC10F220](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en023673)?

[image: PIC10F220]

They're pretty tiny, and cost only 33p in quantity 100.

It's got an analogue input which you can use to measure the current, and digital I/O pins which can be used to cut the power, and provide a reset input.

[image: PIC10 safety cutout]

The great thing about a microcontroller solution is that it's so flexible. You can choose to make it:

- Cut the power at 500mA, and not switch it on again until the system is power cycled.
- Try switching on again after some time.
- Only cut the power if the current draw is more than 500mA for 2 seconds.
- Whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot man for this solution. Looks pretty simple and cost-effective solution. I will try out with the circuit that you have provided.                                             Thanks again !